# USD payments not converting to Rupees in WooCommerce Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, instamojo

1. I have a ecommerce portal setup on WooCommerce/WordPress and the store is open for everyone.
2. The primary currency is USD.
3. I am using Paypal and there is no problem processing payments.
   However, my main customer base is also India, and Paypal doesn't support in India yet.
4. I have installed Instamojo and PayUMoney which are popular in India.
5. The problem is as the currency is in USD, now when someone transacts and wants to make payment via Instamojo or PayUMoney, the dollar value is not getting converted to Indian Rupee. Like if the cart value is $15, RS 15/- is getting deducted.
6. I need some help now so that I can use USD which will work with PayPal and INR to go with Instamojo
7. So, basically if I select Paypal the USD should be processed and when I select Instamojo as Payment, USD amount should be converted to INR before processing.

Please do let me know if you need any further understanding. Hoping to see some break here.

Or suggest if any better payment gateway which works with above conditions.

Best,
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using the **WooCommerce Payment Gateways Currency Converter** Plugin

The plugin is providing you featured as showed in the image below.

**Admin Setting**

---

[image]

Visit this web page it may be helping you more.

https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-payment-gateways-currency-converter/

You can download plugin by click on this **`Plugin can be downloaded here`** text on web page.